# Well formed CSS to LESS

Tags: html, css, generator, less

As a UX designer I am trying to optimize my work flow.
I want to go from HTML to well formed CSS to LESS as quick as I can.
The idea: Post your HTML, generate CSS, compile TO less, add the properties for style, and THEN recompile to CSS for deployment.

HTML:

```
<header>
   <nav>
     <ul>
       <li><a></a></li>
       <li><a></a></li>
       <li><a></a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
<header>
```

Outputted CSS using http://lab.xms.pl/css-generator/

```
header {  }
header nav {  }
header nav ul {  }
header nav ul li {  }
header nav ul li a {  }
```

Then the LESS version is built with some kind of compiler (THIS IS WHAT I NEED)

```
header{
**declarations**
  nav{
  **declarations**
    ul{
    **declarations**        
      li{
      **declarations**
        a{
         **declarations**
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

Finally recompile to normal CSS when development is finished and ready to deploy with a tool such as http://wearekiss.com/simpless (just an example I'm sure there are plenty of tools like this)

I do realize there are things to consider such as mixins vs concatenating rules with tools like Cleancss but nesting is the biggest concern for me as repeating specificity rules over and over again is the most gruesome to build/look at.

To clean out unused CSS we could use unused-css (dot) com or a similar tool.

Does anyone have a tool for accomplishing such as task? 
Would anyone be interested in building this?

Thoughts-suggestions-meetups w/e are welcome. Automating just this task at least could really lift alot of us to the next level, so please don't write if off, consider carefully what I'm suggesting before yelling "REWRITE IT" "TOUGH IT OUT" etc

Thanks in advance and hope to hear some good input.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea, wouldn't it generate a ton of CSS selectors you won't end up using? It seems easier just to pull up a page on one half and starting coding in LESS on the other half. LESS already offers a way to make nested selectors easier as well. I might be missing the point here.

Comment: I think this entire process is a bit flawed. The whole idea of CSS is that the rules cascade down and you don't need rules for every element at every DOM level. This seems to encourage ignoring the fundamentals of CSS.

Comment: This is why I just included a quick line to use a cleaner tool such as unused-css.com

Comment: Please people think before you answer. OF COURSE we would remove unused CSS rules! DUH! I'm asking for a functionality of nesting rules we DID use.

Comment: @JeffScottWard I am thinking—and very clearly. In my opinion what you're doing encourages using CSS improperly, possibly more so than auto-generating "scaffolding" code in other languages. Stack Overflow also isn't really someplace to ask for an entire program to be written for you.

Comment: Yeah that kind of attitude will get you great answers. I agree with David and Andrew that while this may sound like a good idea, it would turn out to be completely impractical. There would be so many selectors, probably far more than the amount of selectors you'd actually style.

Comment: Didn't mean to come off with an attitude, soprry if I did, but I have had instances where I was just written off too quick before. I just wanted to stress that I think the community at large could benefit from this if it made sense, this would not just be for me. Thank you andrew for taking the time on this I do appreciate it. @Dan, unused selectors would be removed naturally.

Comment: Isn't the point of using LESS so that you code "less" already? Why would you want to code it normally then compile it to LESS rather than just write it in LESS to begin with? Other than perhaps porting over old css into LESS automatically, I'm not sure I see the point.

Comment: The point is to build out a css hierarchy that is identical to the html hierarchy on the fly, so literally the only thing you actually need to do is do the styling properities, all the rule building is good already, and its syntax is 'less' :-P.

Comment: And in theory, this would allow you to 100% seperate markup from styling, no more presentational class in your html, or classes at all for that matter. It probably is impractical but a cool execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP implementation of the LESS preprocessor has a tool called Lessify. You can download it from [the project's git repo](https://github.com/leafo/lessphp) or [give it a go online](http://leafo.net/lessphp/lessify/). I hope this is what you needed.

Comment: THANK YOU MINGOS! It at least did what I just asked for, maybe it can do more! I think css -> to less could be a huge step for both learning and bringing old projects into the future.